# Is there a way to display a jsp page in a modal window on button click?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp page that contains some text and a button . Is there a way to display another jsp page  in a modal window when the button is clicked?

Comment: You could put an `<iframe>` inside the window.

Comment: iframes in modals is very common, or use ajax load a partial